# Cygwin can't set the db_home

Tags: cygwin

Everytime I start Cygwin it start in the windows $HOME, and even after I change the db_home: /%H/cygwin(/) in C:\cygwin64\etc it still starts in my home directory.

EDIT: I have tried db_home:   /%H/cygwin64/home

Comment: the `db_home` setting in `/etc/nsswitch.conf` should be `/home/%U`

Comment: @matzeri and where should it bring me, it again put all the files in the c Drive (my home directory for windows), after I tried `/home/%U/cygwin64` to put it in a folder that is on the c drive, it just opened in the c

Comment: Where have you installed your Cygwin ? The default should be `C:\cygwin64` and `/home/%U` should give as result `C:\cygwin64\home\your_user_name`